# How to start editing new row/column added to grid immediately

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm working on a small application where I want to add a new row to a single-column `EditorGridPanel`, and each time a new row is added I want it to be in edit mode so the user can write the wanted text into it immediately.

Relevant code from [a complete jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uo3sjp0j/):

```
store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        autoDestroy: true,
        storeId: 'myStore',
        idIndex: 0,
        fields: [
            { name: 'group', type: 'string' }
        ],
        data: [],
        listeners: {
            add: function(t, records, index) {
                // This call causes problems
                grid.startEditing(index, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

When the `add` event in the store is triggered, which should be *after* the record has been added, it seems it still hasn't been added to the actual grid, only the store. This causes an error in in the grid component.

Is there any other event, possibly in the grid component, that can be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of timing. You are trying to add the grid when you add the record to the store and it takes a little time for the two things to be in sync. You should try putting your code on the `rowinserted` event handler of the `grid.getView()` .

For your code to work the way you have it right now, simply change it to:

```
store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    autoDestroy: true,
    storeId: 'myStore',
    idIndex: 0,
    fields: [
        { name: 'group', type: 'string' }
    ],
    data: [],
    listeners: {
        add: function(t, records, index) {
            Ext.defer(function() {
                grid.startEditing(index, 0);
            },10);
        }
    }
});
```

Doing this will give enough time for the info between the store and the grid to be in sync.